# Parallelize Game of Life Openmp: not working for large matrix

Tags: c, malloc, openmp

Here is my code for Conway's Game of Life with 4 neighbors. I have to experiment with matrices of size 128X128, 256X256, 512X512, 1024x1024, 2048x2048.

The sequential code doesn't run(the run window opens and immediately exits) after 512 sized matrix while the parallelized code doesn't run after 256 sized matrix. There are no compilation errors though.

Till the array of size 256, it works fine and gives a speed-up of 5.44. 
Could anyone please help?

Allocating grid:

```
grid= malloc(sizeof(int*)*ROWS);
for (i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++){
   grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*COLS);
}
```

Parallel code:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{

for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
    grid=process(grid, ROWS, COLS);
}
}
```

function process:

```
int process(int **grid, int ROWS, int COLS) {
    int population = 0;
    int neighbors;
    int tempGrid[ROWS][COLS];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int t=0;

    #pragma omp for private(t, neighbors, tempGrid) 
    for(t = 0; t < ROWS*COLS; t++) {
        i=t/COLS;
        j=t%COLS;
            if (grid[i][j] == -1) {
                continue;
            }
            neighbors = neighbors(i, j, grid, ROWS, COLS);
            if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
                if (neighbors == 3) {
                    tempGrid[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    tempGrid[i][j] = 0;
                }
            } else if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
                if (neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3) {
                    tempGrid[i][j] = 0;
                } else {
                    tempGrid[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }

    }

    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {

            grid[i][j] = tempGrid[i][j];
//           printf("%d", grid[i][j]); 
        }
//       printf("\n"); 
    }
//   printf("\n"); 
return grid;
```

function neighbors:

```
int neighbors(int row, int col, int **grid, int ROWS, int COLS) {
    int neighbors = 0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    for(i = row - 1; i < row + 2; i++) {
        for(j = col - 1; j < col + 2; j++) {
            if (i == row && j == col) {
                continue;
            }
            if (i > -1 && j > -1 && i < ROWS && j < COLS && i==row && j!=col) {
                neighbors += grid[i][j];
            }
            if (i > -1 && j > -1 && i < ROWS && j < COLS && i!=row && j==col) {
                neighbors += grid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate `tempGrid` with `malloc`. The array is too big for the stack, i.e. too big to be a local variable.

Comment: Hey!! I tried allocating tempGrid with malloc . Its working for sequential program. But it breaks down with the openmp directives and gives this error dialogbox "The instruction at 0x… referenced memory at 0x00000000".  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the code tried to dereference a NULL pointer. I would check the return value from `malloc` and make sure that it didn't return NULL.